# Substring multifasta file using python

Tags: python, substring, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I am trying to extract sequences from a multifasta file from position 2 to 8 (seeds of microRNAs). To do this I have written a small python script. The script works but I couldn't write an output file. Could anyone help me or point me in the right direction?

Thanks

**Script:**

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for index, record in enumerate(SeqIO.parse("file.fasta","fasta")):
    seed= record.seq[1:8]
    a = (print(">" + record.id + '\n\ + seed)
```

**Output:**

```
>aga-miR-12417-5p
AGUCGUU
>aga-miR-12418-3p
GUUCGAU
>aga-miR-12419-5p
GCUGUUC
```

Comment: Let me make sure I understand, you want to write to a file instead of print to console?

Comment: Yes, at the moment I can see the results in console but I cannot send it to an output file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `SeqIO.write()`, this would be the most similar way to your current structure:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

with open("out_file.fasta", "w") as out_f:
    for index, record in enumerate(SeqIO.parse("file.fasta","fasta")):
        record.seq = record.seq[1:8]
        SeqIO.write(record, out_f, "fasta")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to write to a simple plain text file you can do:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
with open('output_file', 'w') as output:
    for index, record in enumerate(SeqIO.parse("file.fasta","fasta")):
        seed= record.seq[1:8]
        output.writeline(">" + record.id)
        output.writeline(seed)
```

Comment: This is not the correct way- they should use the Biopython parser- in particular this will be wrong if the header includes whitespace since the `.id` is split at the first whitespace

Comment: @Chris_Rands was it a requirement that the output file be parsable by Biopython again? the op just wanted to put in a file whatever they put in the console.

Comment: the point is this produces the wrong output for many files, e.g. `>1 missing\nATG\n`